# Match names from two text in Python

Tags: python

I have a long text where I want to see if one or more names from a txt file appears.

*Example*

**Text1=** Hello my name Is Peter Jensen and I know Pete Hawkins yes I do.

I have several names each on their own line

**Text 2=**
John Doe

Peter Jensen

Pete Hawkins

Michael Love

Is it possible to make a python script that gives an output with all the names in my text1 that match 100% in my Text2?

Expected output:
Peter Jensen,Pete Hawkins

I tried this:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\names1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    text1 = file.read() 
with open('C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\names2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    text2 = file.read() 
findnames = re.compile(r'([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)')  
for possible_name in set(findnames.findall(text1)):
    if possible_name in text2:
        return possible_name
    return "No match"
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Please, take some minutes to read the 'how to ask' section, you need to provide your code with some prove of effort

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make such a script, which means that you can make it too. Have you tried something that we can help you with? Please see [ask] and provide a [example].

Comment: Sorry I have attached now what I tried. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
text = 'Hello my name Is Peter Jensen and I know Pete Hawkins yes I do.'

names_list = ['John Doe','Peter Jensen','Pete Hawkins','Michael Love']

for name in names_list:
    finder = text.find(name)
    if finder > -1:
        print('found name:', name)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for you time and effort. It returns only the first letter J when I try to run this?

Comment: The code was fully tested, and it prints the whole `name`, as found in the `names_list`. Maybe you have done a slight modification where you are printing `name[finder]` ? Because `finder` returns the first position where the `name` is in `text`

Answer (score 0):

First, get the names as list from text file

```
with open('the file') as file:
    names = file.readlines()
```

After that thir are 2 methods.

**method 1**

```py
text = 'Hello my name Is Peter Jensen and I know Pete Hawkins yes I do.'

matches = []
for name in names:
    if name in text:
        matches.append(name)


print(matches)
```

**method 2**

```py
import re

text = 'Hello my name Is Peter Jensen and I know Pete Hawkins yes I do.'

matches = re.findall(f"{'|'.join(names)}", text)

print(matches)
```

Both give the exact expected output.

Comment: Method1 - It says that cannot convert python.runtime.object to string. I tried return str(matches) instead and gives me a lot of results like this: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'e', ' ', 's', ' ', 'P', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'J', 'e', 'n', 's', 'e', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'n', ' ', ' ', 'k', 'n', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'P', 'e', 't', 'e', ' ', 'H', 'a', 'w', 'k', 'i', 'n', 's', ' ', 'e', 's', ' ', ' ', 'o']

Method2 - It says that cannot convert python.runtime.object to string. Same erooro as Method 1 but when I try to add return str(matches) it returns only: ['J']

Comment: @dataimport1 for me it works perfect, their is something wrong with your code, I can't say anything without viewing it...

make sure `names` is a list of strings

Comment: I added this to the read=names = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file] and now it seems to work. Only small problem. It only return ['Peter Jensen'] the first match not both. Could you help whats wrong?
with open('C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\names.txt', 'r') as file:
 names = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
  
text2='Hello my name Is Peter Jensen and I know Pete Hawkins yes I do.'
Matches = []
for name in names:
if name in text2:
matches.append(name)
return str(matches)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be rather simple to make such a script. However, as you didn't say what you wanted to do with the list, I will assume you want to print it to standard output (generally, a terminal).

So for the sake of this example, I will assume you have a file named `text.txt` with the following contents:

```
Hello my name Is Peter Jensen and I know Pete Hawkins yes I do.
I really do know Peter Jensen I tell you!
```

and a file named `names.txt` with the following contents:

```
John Doe
Peter Jensen
Pete Hawkins
Michael Love
```

A simple script to print your list to standard output would be like this:

```py
# open the text.txt file and get its contents.
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    txt = f.read()

# open the names.txt file and get its contents
# make each line a string in a list of strings
with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
    names = [name.strip() for name in f.readlines()]

# print out each name in the list if that name is in the text.txt file
print([name for name in names if name in txt])
```

You could also do this as for loop like this:

```py
names_in_text = []

for name in names:
    if name in txt:
        names_in_text.append(name)

print(names_in_text)
```